# Ambiguous outer join when Left join two tables but duplicate records when link all three

Tags: sql, ms-access, outer-join

I have three tables:

```
Table1 - Customer profile
customer id
customer name
customer country
customer total sales

Table2 - Contract list
contract number
customer id
customer state
contract sales
business code

Table3 - Business index
business code
business type
```

Each `customer` has `xxx amount of contracts`, and each `'customer total sales'` in `Table1` equals to sum of the `'contract sales'` in `Table2` for that particular customer.

What I want to list is all customer name, each customer's total sales, country; also list each customer's state and business type.

My query tried to pull `customer id, customer name, customer country, customer total sales from Table1` and `customer state from Table2` and `business type from Table3`. But when I Left Join Table1.customer id-->Table2.customer id, and left join Table2.business code-->Table3.business type, it pull all data I wanted but there were xxx row of duplicate records for each customer.

Then, I attempt to find out what caused it by removing one join and changing the join properties. It pops up message for `'ambiguous outer join'` when:

1. I remove either one of the join leaving only two tables linked with one Left join;
2. I change either one of the joins to either Right join or Inner join

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? I'm not sure I fully understand your question but it sounds like you are looking for a `full outer join`. Can you add some example data and the expected output?

Comment: What query are you using? are you using group by? Also as @a_horse_with_no_name says, which DBMS? MySQL behaves somewhat different than MSSql or Oracle. Are you using group by in your query?

Comment: @user3027035 - Please include the queries you've attempted.  Also, please update your question with sample starting data, and the results retrieved for that sample.  As an aside, unless you have performance issues, Storing the 'total' row in `Customer` is begging for it to _not_ match the actual total from `Contract`...

Comment: Hi a_horse_with_no_name, I'm using MS Access.
the result I got was
101, ABC, Australia, 200, NSW, RETAIL
101, ABC, Australia, 200, NSW, RETAIL
101, ABC, Australia, 200, NSW, RETAIL
103, EFG, Australia, 300, QLD, INFRASTRUCTURE
103, EFG, Australia, 300, QLD, INFRASTRUCTURE
105, HIJ, Australia, 450, VIC, TRAINING
105, HIJ, Australia, 450, VIC, TRAINING
...
the first customer ABC has three contracts, both the 2nd and third one has two. What I want to see would be 
101, ABC, Australia, 200, NSW, RETAIL
103, EFG, Australia, 300, QLD, INFRASTRUCTURE
105, HIJ, Australia, 450, VIC, TRAINING

Answer (score 0):

In T-SQL:
As table `Customer_profile` and `Contract_list` both have `customer_id` column `table alias` should be used to avoid ambigous column name error. Also to remove duplicate records `Distinct` key word should be added.Following query should work:

```
select distinct cp.customer_id,
       cp.customer_name,
       cp.customer_country,
       cp.customer_total_sales ,
       cl.customer_state,
       bi.business_type 
from Customer_profile cp
left join Contract_list cl on cp.customer_id = cl.customer_id 
left join Business_index bi on bi.business_code = cl.business_code ;
```